# WCF concurrent connection configuration

Tags: wcf, .net-3.5, performancecounter, perfmon

We have a new Win 2012 server hosting a legacy .NET 3.5 WCF Service (with 22 endpoints and maybe a couple of hundred operations) and we are having some performance issues and want to control the number of connections.

We have attached perfmon `Web Service/Current Connections` counter and see this value repeatedly rise to a steady 24 connections (with occasional spikes to 25).

[image: Perfmon view showing Current Connections]

We have tried managing the number of connections using `system.ServiceModel\behaviors\serviceBehaviors\behavior\serviceThrottling`. We have tried default values, low numbers, recommended and high numbers:

```
<!-- default --> 
<serviceThrottling />

<!-- low --> 
<serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="5" maxConcurrentSessions="10" maxConcurrentInstances="15"/>

<!-- recommended (2 processors) --> 
<serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="32" maxConcurrentSessions="200" maxConcurrentInstances="232"/>

<!-- high--> 
<serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="2000" maxConcurrentSessions="2000" maxConcurrentInstances="2000"/>
```

[image]

1. Where else might this connection limit be getting set?
2. Have we added the correct counter in perfmon?

**Update**

We've added another client, and doubled the number of requests that the WS server is processing. So this has proved that the throttling is occuring upstream. The upstream client is a .NET3.5 ASP.NET website. The connection to the WCF service is via a wsHttpBinding.

We have already added `system.net\connectionManagement\maxconnection` and this hasn't had any impact.

What other settings might throttle outgoing ASP.NET connections to a WCF service?

Answer (score 0):

please try adding this section and test the performance again:

```
  <system.net>
    <connectionManagement>
      <add address="*" maxconnection="250" />
    </connectionManagement>
  </system.net>
```

the default value is 2.

Comment: I already had this setting in the client, but have now also added this to the WCF service too. The `Current Connections` has now jumped temporarily to 34 and then settled back to 24 again. I don't think this has helped, but thanks anyway.

Comment: This makes me feel like this is a connection limit on an upstream service? We using Jmeter to apply load via a website and I am running 120 threads on there.